# P5.JS Animated GIF shows all frames when it renders

Tags: javascript, gif, p5.js, animated-gif

This is my first submitted question. So please go easy!

I have made a very simple run/jump game using p5.js.

Game: https://simongowing1.github.io/the-art-collector-game/
Code: https://github.com/simongowing1/the-art-collector-game

Originally the 'player' was static, but I just added an animated gif (made up of two images) so that it appears to be walking.

When I check in the browser both layers of the gif show at once, so the effect does not work.

I *think* this is something to do with the rendering of the image. Having checked out some other solutions on stack, I tried 'createImage()' and 'createImg()' instead of simply 'loadimage()' but both of these resulted in other elements from the site disappearing.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

I've pasted my code from the 'game.js' file below for reference

```
class Game {
constructor() {
    this.backgroundImage;
    this.tokenImage;
    

}
setup() {
    this.background = new Background();
    this.player = new Player();
    this.tokens = [];
    this.obstacles = [];
}

preload() {
    this.backgroundImage = [
        { src:loadImage('assets/empty_gallery_long.jpg'), x: 0, speed: 1.5}
    ]
    this.playerImage = loadImage('assets/Player1-walking-front.gif');
    this.playerImageBk = loadImage('assets/Player1-walking-back.gif');
    this.tokenImage1 = loadImage('assets/token1.png');
    this.tokenImage2 = loadImage('assets/token2.png');
    this.tokenImage3 = loadImage('assets/token3.png');
    this.obstacleImage = loadImage('assets/Obstacle1.png');
    this.backgroundMusic = createAudio('assets/01 Windowlicker.mp3');
    this.jumpSound = createAudio('assets/jump.mp3');
    this.saleSound = createAudio('assets/Sale.m4a');
    this.breakingSound = createAudio('assets/breaking.m4a')
}

gamelogic() {
    if (counter === remainingTime) {}
}

draw() {
    clear(); 
    this.background.draw();
    //console.log('hello')
    if (frameCount === 10 || frameCount % 500 === 0) {
        this.tokens.push(new Token(this.tokenImage1))
        //console.log('now');
    }

    this.tokens.forEach(function (token) {
        token.draw();
    })

    this.tokens = this.tokens.filter(
        (token) => {
            if (token.collision(this.player))
            {
                console.log('got it!');
                return false
            } else if (token.x < 0 - token.width) {
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        })

        this.player.draw();

        if (frameCount === 300 || frameCount % 1200 === 0) {
            this.obstacles.push(new Obstacle(this.obstacleImage))
            //console.log('now');
        }

        this.obstacles.forEach(function (obstacle) {
            obstacle.draw();
        })

        
        this.obstacles = this.obstacles.filter(
            (obstacle) => {
                if (obstacle.collision(this.player))
                {
                   // console.log('CRASH');
                    return false

                } else {
                    return true
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Split that gif into frames using free online editors like ezgif
Then name all frames in order player1, player2 and so on
and write code like this :-

this.playerImage = loadAnimation('player1', 'player2', 'player3');